# В чем ошибка фильтрации диапазона дат DataGridView SQLite?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, sqlite, datagridview

На форме таблицы оценок нужно сделать фильтрацию по дате. Есть два DateTimePicker - стартовое и конечное значение даты.

Сначала создается такая же таблица как без фильтрации, затем проходиться циклом по ней и удаляются строки где дата меньше стартовой или больше конечной, и заполняется DataGridView. Последние строчки это просто отображение кнопки очистки фильтра.

```
private void DateTimeStart_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DateTimeStart.Value <= DateTimeFinish.Value)
        {
            DataTable dt = ConnectingDataBase.GetDataTable("SELECT Marks.id as ID, Students.last_name||\" \"||Students.name||\" \"||Students.father_name AS Ученик," +
            "\r\n Marks.value as Оценка, Marks.date as Дата, Disciplins.id, Students.id\r\n " +
            "FROM Marks INNER JOIN Disciplins ON Disciplins.id = Marks.discipline_id" + QueryWhereDiscipline +
            " INNER JOIN Students ON Students.id = Marks.student_id " + QueryWhereGroup);

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString());
                if (date < DateTimeStart.Value || date > DateTimeFinish.Value)
                    dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[i]);

            }

            MarksGrid.DataSource = dt;
        }
        else Errors.ShowPred("Начальная дата фильтра должна быть меньше конечной.");

        if (DateTimeFinish.Value != DateTime.Now && DateTimeStart.Value != ConnectingDataBase.GetStartTime())
            DataClear.Visible = true;
        else DataClear.Visible = false;
    }
```

Работает очень странно. По месяцам все работает, но если ввести стартовое значение приближенным к конечному, то некоторые удаляются, а некоторые нет.

До выбора даты вручную стартовое значение равно старшей записи оценки:

[image: До выбора дат]

После выбора другого месяца все работает ОК:

[image: Фильтрация в диапазоне одного месяца]

А вот если хочу вывести даты в одном месяце и конкретном промежутке дней выводиться каша-малаша:

[image: В одном месяце и промежутке дней]

> А еще отладка с точкой остановы не работает виснет VS и Windows, еще и VS блокирует завершение работы ПК, поэтому нормально значения не могу прочитать :с И появилось когда я это событие писала. Без точки отладка работает, приходиться другими способами читать. Если знаете, напишите пожалуйста, буду признательна, хоть к теме не относиться.

Comment: [DataView.RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov знаете как через RowFilter это сделать? Изначально так и хотела, но SQLite содержит только 4 типа данных TEXT INTEGER BLOB и REAL, не знаю как перевести TEXT в DateTime конкретно в запросе фильтра.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  Cтолбец Дата - TEXT, DateTimeStart/Finish - DateTime           
                (MarksGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Дата <= '{DateTimeStart.Value}' " +
                    $"AND Дата >= '{DateTimeFinish.Value}'";

Answer (score 0):

Спустя многочисленных проб узнала что в sqlite все-таки есть функции перевода текста в Date Type, например по шаблону yyyy-MM-dd. Собственно простеньким sql-запросом получилась рабочая фильтрация))
А вот с RowFilter такое преобразования не работает.